# NameError when calling upon variable that I have defined within a def - Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code is meant to allow the user to input a name- but if they input numbers, then it will display an error ('No numbers please!') and prompt them to input their name again. This process will continue in a loop until the user inputs a string with no number characters.

However, If the user inputs a pure alphabetical string-

```
if not any(char.isdigit() for char in name):
    break
```

Then the loop will be broken and the result of the input will be turned into a list for use later in the program. *Here is where the error comes in*:
When the loop is broken, I get this error:

```
    namelist = list(name.lower().strip(" "))
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

As you can see below, I have already defined the variable name as the result of an input within the naming() definition. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

```
def naming():
name = input ("please input your name: ")
while any(char.isdigit() for char in name):
    print ("\nNo numbers please!\n")
    naming()

    if not any(char.isdigit() for char in name):
        break


naming()


#making the name into a list
namelist = list(name.lower().strip(" "))
```

Comment: Names defined within a function *are local to that function*. If you need access to it outside, `return` and assign it.

Comment: Your indentation is not correct, please check it again in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` has its scope limited to only the function, which is why you can't access it in the global scope for `namelist`.

One way to solve this is to return the value from your function:

```
def get_name():
    name = input ("please input your name: ")
    while any(char.isdigit() for char in name):
        print ("\nNo numbers please!\n")
        name = input ("please input your name: ")
    return name

name = get_name()
namelist = list(name.lower().strip(" "))
```